# Django error message doesn't declare an explicit app label

Tags: django

I am getting this error message while trying to add a model form to my django site. It was all working fine before I added the form code and now I cannot access the site. Any help on how to fix it appreciated. I need the form to save to the database.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 448, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 627, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/francisbarrott/Desktop/School/django/NEA_website/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/francisbarrott/Desktop/School/django/NEA_website/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 133, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in __new__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

These are my installed apps: INSTALLED_APPS = [ "django.contrib.admin", "django.contrib.auth", "django.contrib.contenttypes", "django.contrib.sessions", "django.contrib.messages", "django.contrib.staticfiles", "NEA_website.apps.accounts", "NEA_website.models.NewRoundForm", "django.contrib.sites", "django.contrib.contenttypes.models", "NewRoundForm", "django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType", "django.contrib.contenttypes"

Comment: These are my installed apps: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "NEA_website.apps.accounts",
    "NEA_website.models.NewRoundForm",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes.models",
    "NewRoundForm",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes"

Comment: Show us your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, and the location of your model/forms in your project. [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71936680/edit) to include this information rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: 1. You have to add the app name in to Installed_apps list in settings.py. 2. You have to add the app_name = <app_name> at the top of each app urls.py file.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but is my app name the name of the file?